# How I can make this sphere on center every time when size of widow change

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

My code is:

```
<script>

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );

camera.position.z = 3;

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

render();

</script>
```

I use three.js for making a 3D sphere.
And I need it, to be on center of screen every time, when widow change size.
Right now, if I move size of widows it will breaks.
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a listener for the window resize event to change the camera.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );

camera.position.z = 3;

// Add listener for window resize.
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

render();
```

```css
body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r134/build/three.min.js"></script>
```